# How to check which IP address is blocked in Inbound rules of Firewall?

Tags: networking, ip, windows-firewall

I have blocked IP addresses from many countries due to some attack incidents happened on my server. Now in my inbound rules, I have more than 100 entries of different IP address range. Now some of my customers IP addresses belong to one of those ranges which are blocked. Now its being very difficult for me to find which list contains that particular range which I need to unblock. My question is is there a way to find whether IP address is blocked or not? And also how to find quickly which inbound rule has that blocked IP without manually checking all rules?

I got list of IP address from [here](http://ipdeny.com/ipblocks/)